# Maven stop on network errors

Tags: maven, gitlab

Launching a maven command using `-U,--update-snapshots` option.
Pointing to a private registry (gitlab) and using a token for login in `settings.xml`

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpHeaders>
          <property>
            <name>Deploy-Token</name>
            <value>[omissis]</value>
          </property>
        </httpHeaders>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

When the token is there, it works ok.

```
[INFO] Downloading from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/[omissis]/develop-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded from gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/[omissis]/develop-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.0 kB at 1.2 kB/s)
```

The problem is when the token is not there and the depencencies are already in the `.m2/repositories`. The difference is very subtle from the log because the `Downloaded` line doesn't print.

Is there any flag for the maven command or setting in the pom to force a failure and exit in this case?

Comment: Why do you have frequent network errors?

Comment: @JFabianMeier the network works properly, the edge case is the missing token (the skeleton is committed into VSC but the token is added only locally)